# Python - prime number algorithm doesn't work with higher numbers

Tags: python, primes

I´m new at python and I have problem with my simple program.

I have found some simple algorithm that can tell if input number is prime number or not. Evrything works fine with input numbers like 2 or 13. The problem happens when I use higher number (and I need to use higher numbers only).

```
num = 3231817448941

if num > 1:  
   for i in range(2,num):  
       if (num % i) == 0:  
           print(num,"is not a prime number")  
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)  
           break  
   else:  
    print(num, "is a prime number")
         
else:  
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

My number input is 3231817448941. Because this number is prime number it should print:

```
Output should be:
3231817448941 is a prime number
```

But after runing this program my concole is empty and nothing is printed.
Also when I use similar number with same length that is not prime number then it works.

As I said I'm new at python and I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Maybe your loop just takes a long time to finish. As well it might, since it is required to do three trillion iterations.

Comment: It does work, you just need to be more patient.

Comment: you could optimize your algorithm for faster output

Comment: It works but loop has to iterate over 3 trillion times

Comment: Assuming that you're testing a billion numbers per second (a *vast* overestimate), it would take 3231 seconds to test all the numbers.  But there's no need to test all the numbers - if there is a factor at all, there will be a factor that is no greater than the square root of the number.  And there's no point in testing even numbers, once you've tested for divisibility by 2.

Comment: Maybe if you wont print the false case it would be little bit faster

Comment: To add more conditions like suggested by @jasonharper. You can sum the individual digits and see if they are divisible by three. Then the number itself is divisible by three. If the number ends in 0 or 5, then it's divisible by 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One change to speed up the process A LOT

```
num = 3231817448941

if num > 1:       
   for i in range(2,int(num**0.5)+1):  # Dont have to check to n, just sqrt(n)
       if (num % i) == 0:  
           print(num,"is not a prime number")  
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)  
           break  
   else:  
    print(num, "is a prime number")
         
else:  
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

You can find more optimizations [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-check-whether-a-number-is-prime-or-not/)

Comment: i'll add those edge cases